# Bit masking result inconsistency

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm tying to learn about bit masking and I have a question about certain results. Here's some example code.

```
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen ( "testFile.jpg" , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

    for (unsigned long long e = 0; e < lSize; e++){
        unsigned short val1 = buffer[e] & 0x3;
        cout << val1 << endl;
        if (1 == val1){

        }
        if (1 == buffer[e] & 0x3){
            //what does buffer[e] & 0x3 equal when I don't set it equal to an unsigned short.
        }
    }
```

So if I output the value of `val1` I always get a value between 0 and 3. But when I do a comparison without assigning a type to `buffer[e] & 0x3` I don't always get the same result. I tried to output `buffer[e] & 0x3` to see what it equals but I get an error. So my question is what are the possible values of `buffer[e] & 0x3` when it is being used in the second if statement. Thanks.

Comment: You should not use `malloc` this way in C++. For a drop-in replacement use `buffer = new(std::nothrow) char[lSize];`

Comment: Sounds good, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that"s because of *operator precedence*

```
7   == !=   For relational = and ≠ respectively
8   &   Bitwise AND
```

so `==` has priority on `&`

```
(1 == buffer[e] & 0x3)
```

isn't the same thing as

```
(1 == (buffer[e] & 0x3))
```

but is

```
((1 == buffer[e]) & 0x3)
```

(and amounts to `(1 == buffer[e])` because masking 0 or 1 with 3 has no effect)

what you want is `(1 == (buffer[e] & 0x3))`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. There are times when it was equating to true. So in that case how does the & 0x3 effect the results in your last example.

Comment: it doesn't. since result can only be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a problem with operator precedence:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

```
1 == buffer[e] & 0x3
```

is equivalent to

```
(1 == buffer[e]) & 0x3
```